# Cordova Android Status Bar Color

Tags: android, cordova, html-framework-7

What are the ways of changing android status bar color dynamically in runtime and statically in source code ?

I'm using Cordova + Framework7

Answer (score 0):

Use Cordova plugin statusbar. 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/